# The number of badges is always one (cloud function )

Tags: ios, swift, typescript, push-notification, google-cloud-functions

i have send notification from cloud function if the node is change  in firebase successfully but the badge number is always show (1) even i send multiple notification .

my code in cloud function (typescript ) :

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
exports.sendPushNotificationToUpdate = functions.database.ref('/orders/{Id}/OrderStatus').onWrite((snapshot, context) => {
    let status = snapshot.after.val();
    console.log('status : ' + status);
    if (status != 'Done' && status != 'Rejected') {
        return null;
    }

    else {
        const Id = context.params.Id;

        console.log('id : ' + Id);

        return admin.database().ref('/orders/' + Id).once('value').then(function (snap) {
            const tokenId = snap.val().tokenId;
            console.log('tokenId : ' + snap.val().tokenId);
            let payload = {
                notification: {
                    title: 'my App',
                    body: '',
                    badge: '1',
                    sound: 'default',
                }
            }
            if (status == 'Done') {
                payload = {
                    notification: {
                        title: 'My App',
                        body: 'your order is done',
                        badge: '1',
                        sound: 'default',
                    }
                }


            }
            else if (status == 'Rejected') {
                payload = {
                    notification: {
                        title: 'My App',
                        body: 'your order is rejected',
                        badge: '1',
                        sound: 'default',
                    }
                }

            }
            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokenId, payload).then(response => {
                console.log('update respose');
                console.log(response);
            });
        });
    }


});
```

my code in Xcode (swift) :

```
 func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
       let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        print("tap on on forground app",userInfo)
        Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        let content = response.notification.request.content
        let badgeNumber = content.badge as! Int
        UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber  =  badgeNumber + 1

        completionHandler()
          let actionIdentifier = response.actionIdentifier
        switch actionIdentifier {
        case UNNotificationDismissActionIdentifier: // Notification was dismissed by user

            completionHandler()
        case UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier: // App was opened from notification

            completionHandler()
        default:
            completionHandler()
        }
    }
```

my code just work fine and do all the jobs but the badge number it stay in one any help that will be great thanks a lot .

Comment: This isn't a `Swift` question, it's a `typescript` one. Your code is sending `badge: '1'` - so that needs to be updated to send the correct badge count.

Answer (score 0):

In you cloud function (typescript) you are sending 1 in badge, so will get 1 only, Change the badge number as 2 or 3, then it will reflect in didReceive method.

You should put some logic to make the badge number dynamic in cloud function (typescript).

Comment: i know the problem in payload (badge: '1') but i do not  know how make that logic any help that will be great

Comment: you want to pass your current badge number to server by a webservice, then while sending push notification you have to add +1 with that badge number.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber += 1
```